# Django : Cannot assign must be a instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to fetch the non-str objects of one model into another model...

This is my models:

```
class Selectdatefield(models.Model):
     User       = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name="Users",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
     Start_Date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
     End_Date   = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class Journal(models.Model):
     User       = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
     company    = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='Companyname')
     start_date = models.ForeignKey(Selectdatefield,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='startdate')
     end_date   = models.ForeignKey(Selectdatefield,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='enddate')
     Date       = models.DateField()
     By         = models.ForeignKey(Ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Debitledgers')
     To         = models.ForeignKey(Ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Creditledgers')
     Debit      = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
     Credit     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
```

I have tried this in my journal create view:

```
  class journalCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
        model = journal
        form_class  = journalForm

        def form_valid(self, form):
              form.instance.User = self.request.user
              c = company.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
              form.instance.Company = c
              s = selectdatefield.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk3'])
              form.instance.start_date = s
              form.instance.end_date = s.End_Date
              return super(journalCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

I want to fetch the end date of selectdate automatically in my journal model when the journal form is submitted...

But getting this error :

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "datetime.date(2018, 10, 6)": "journal.end_date" must be a "selectdatefield" instance.
```

The error is in this line of code:

```
form.instance.end_date = s.End_Date
```

Can someone plz tell me what wrong am I doing in my code???

Comment: s.End_Date is not an instance its date you need to pass an instance like s and in that case you dont need two seprate fields in your journal jus replace with one foriegn key like some_date = models.ForeignKey(Selectdatefield,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='startdate')

Answer (score 2):

Foreign keys in Django need to be assigned an object, not a value. The error tells you that you are trying to assign a `DateTime` value to a field, where it only accepts a `Selectdatefield` object.

Since you already have a `Selectdatefield` object with the value, assign it directly, as you did for the `start_date` attribute:

```
form.instance.start_date = s
form.instance.end_date = s
```